# lme4: Random slopes shared by all observations

Tags: r, lme4

I'm using R's `lme4`. Suppose I have a mixed-effects logistic-regression model where I want some random slopes shared by every observation. They're supposed to be random in the sense that these random slopes should all come from a single normal distribution. This is essentially the same thing as ridge regression, but without choosing a penalty size with cross-validation.

I tried the following code:

```
library(lme4)

ilogit = function(v)
    1 / (1 + exp(-v))

set.seed(20)

n = 100

x1 = rnorm(n)
x2 = rnorm(n)
x3 = rnorm(n)
x4 = rnorm(n)
x5 = rnorm(n)

y.p = ilogit(.5 + x1 - x2)
y = rbinom(n = n, size = 1, prob = y.p)

m1 = glm(
    y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5,
    family = binomial)
print(round(d = 2, unname(coef(m1))))

m2 = glmer(
    y ~ ((x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5)|1),
    family = binomial)
print(round(d = 2, unname(coef(m2))))
```

This yields:

```
Loading required package: Matrix
[1]  0.66  1.14 -0.78 -0.01 -0.16  0.25
Error: (p <- ncol(X)) == ncol(Y) is not TRUE
Execution halted
```

What did I do wrong? What's the right way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *"I want some random slopes shared by every observation. They're supposed to be random in the sense that these random slopes should all come from a single normal distribution."* particularly as it concerns your example code. Your code doesn't include a random slope... I don't think your code is proper syntax, which is causing the error; but I'm not sure what syntax you're trying to use given that your initial comment is unclear.

Comment: @AlexW I'm trying to include five random slopes, one for each of `x1` through `x5`, all of which should apply for all observations. It's just like ordinary least squares, except all the coefficients (other than the intercept) are random effects rather than fixed effects. Does that clarify what I mean? Clearly my code is wrong, but I don't know how to correct it, hence my question.

Comment: <quote> *I'm trying to include five random slopes, one for each of x1 through x5, all of which should apply for all observations.*</quote> That's not a random slope. It's a fixed effect

Comment: @AlexW Perhaps you have a different defintion of "random slope" than I do. Random slopes are a set of slopes that are modeled as being drawn from a common normal distribution. A batch of random slopes differs from a set of fixed effects in that they are shrunk towards 0, as in ridge regression.

Comment: I'm not sure there's added value in the discussion. You appear to have a satisfactory answer. But I think the confusion we're having is due to  phrasing / terminology... And I'm not sure ridge regression is a perfect analogy, since the HLM framework has EB shrinkage; not shrinkage towards the origin on scaled covariates as in ridge regression. In any case, I'm glad you appear to have solved your own problem.

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use lme4? I just ran across an example which might be doing what you need (if I understood you correctly), and it uses nlme. The example is from Rizopolous' book on joint models, isbn 1439872864, chapter 2.2.

Comment: @rumtscho It's been a long time since I worked on this particular project, but thanks for the tip; I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like lme4 can't do this as-is. Here's [what @amoeba said in stats.SE chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33050774#33050774):

> What Kodi wants to do is definitely a mixed model, in the sense of Bates et al. see e.g. eq (2) here https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmer.pdf As far as I can see, X and Z design matrices are equal in this case. However, there is no way one can use lme4 to fit this (without hacking into the code): it allows only particular Z matrices that arise from the model formulas of the type (formula|factor).

> See https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2011q1/015581.html "We intend to allow lmer to be able to use more flexible model matrices for the random effects although, at present, that requires a certain amount of tweaking on the part of the user"

> And https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2009q2/002351.html "I view the variance-covariance structures available in the lme4 package as being related to random-effects terms in the model matrix. A random-effects term is of the form (LMexpr | GrpFac). The expression on the right of the vertical bar is evaluated as a factor, which I call the grouping factor. The expression on the left is evaluated as a linear model expression."

> That's all quotes from Bates. He does say "In future versions of lme4 I plan to allow for extensions of the unconditional variance-covariance structures." (in 2009) but I don't this was implemented.